# Count string data base on space or otherwise any other way

Tags: php, mysql

I have Adjacency list mode structure like that and i want to count all title of parent like Food = 9, Fruit = 6

[image]

For count title using that function

```
  function display_children($parent, $level) 
     {

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM tree '.'WHERE parent="'.$parent.'"');

       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           $data=  str_repeat(' ',$level).$row['title']."\n";
           echo $data;
           $this->display_children($row['title'], $level+1);
        }   
  }
```

call function

```
  display_children('Food',0);
```

Result

by echo  $data; i m getting right result wht i want, but i want to count all like 9

```
 Fruit Green Peer Red Cherry Yellow Banana Meat Pork
```

so plz guide how to count all data when i call function

Comment: Is this the one you're looking for?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a string as the parent key? And you might also want to have a look at [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Could you give an example of what you want to display?

Comment: i want to count all title under parent like Food = 9, so far i m getting tree , but i dont know how to count that tree, and this Adjacency list mode structure not nested

Comment: there is any way i can get data in array after it's easy to count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function display_children($parent, $level) 
{

   $result = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM tree '.'WHERE parent="'.$parent.'"');

   $count = 0;
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       $data=  str_repeat(' ',$level).$row['title']."\n";
       echo $data;
       $count += 1 + $this->display_children($row['title'], $level+1);
    }  
    return $count; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mysql_num_rows`, it will contain the number of rows your query returned.

```
function display_children($parent, $level) 
{
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM tree '.'WHERE parent="'.$parent.'"');
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       $data=  str_repeat(' ',$level).$row['title']."\n";
       echo $data;
       $this->display_children($row['title'], $level+1);
    }   
  }
```

Your menu is query heavy though, and you should really look into a solution like: http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/